# is it possible to run a script periodically in R within a plumber server?

Tags: r, vba, plumber

I would like to run a R-script which calls an external api-server every second.

This R-script generates a dataframe from the received data.

Next I would like to call (import) this dataframe every second from Excel VBA.

In order to do this I intend to use Plumber in R to host a local server with the dataframe which can be called by Excel VBA.

The code can be like (all code related to the stockmarketdata is irrelevant. Only myvar is relevant):

```
library(plumber)
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)

#* @apiTitle Stock Market Data API
#* @apiDescription Example of how to setup a Plumber API with just a few lines of code

#* Provide Stock Market Returns
#* @param symbol Ticker symbol (e.g. 'googl' for Alphabet, 'amzn' for Amazon ...)
#* @param from start date for the time series in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. If not provided the start date is today minus 1 month. 
#* @param to end date for the time series in 'YYYY-DD-DD' format. If not provided, the end date is today.
#* @get /return
#* @serializer json
financial_data <- function(symbol,from = today()-months(1),to = today()) {
  data <- myvar
  data 
}
```

My problem is that Plumber only reacts if I make a call to @get /my_df. If it has to make the call to the external api server after this call it takes time. It would be more efficient if the call to the external api server is already made at that moment. For example by making the external call every second and call @get /my_df from Excel VBA every second.

Is it possible to run such a periodical script within the Plumber server?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're on linux I'd use systemd or cron to trigger a curl command to the external API (something like `curl -X POST --data '{"token":"foobar"}' "https://randomservice.com/api"`) and save the result to disk. Then the plumber API can read the updated data from disk. It's hard to give an example without more details in your question.

Comment: @ thanks pgcudahy . I am on windows 10. My preference would be to save the result in the global environment instead of harddisk since I run the process every minute.

Answer (score 0):

I did succeed by running an additional script in R with a scheduler as in:

```
library(tcltk)

run <- function () { 
  .id <<- tcl("after", 1000, run) # after 1000 ms execute run() again
  cat(as.character(.id), "\n")   
  myvar <<- Sys.time()
}

run()
```

myvar is saved to the Global environment and can be read (and returned) by the Plumber function.

Although if I try to run it once a second and read it in Excel VBA once a second with the funtion below it is only updating in Excel once every 3 seconds. This seems due to the connection between the Plumber server and Excel. If I call the Pluber server with Chrome it is updating once a second correctly.

```
Sub test()

     my_http = "http://127.0.0.1:7206/return?symbol=goog"
     my_output = WorksheetFunction.WebService(my_http)
     Debug.Print my_output

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to deploy your plumber app in the unix OS, you have to define and register a cron job to run your periodic scripts. You can do that in R by using [cronR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/index.html)

Here is an example:

1 - define your job in a file

```
# your CronJob.R file
# Define the function to be executed once a day
run_daily_task <- function() {
  # Your code snippet here
  print("Executing daily task...")
  # For example, you can source a script with your code
  source("/path/to/your/script.R")
}
#register the cron job and save
daily_schedule <- cronR::cron_add(command = run_daily_task , frequency = 'daily', at='11PM', id = 'RDaily')

cronR::cron_save(daily_schedule, file = "daily_schedule")
```

2 - Make sure you source the file on top of your main plumber run file:

```
source('CronJob.R')
```

Please be aware that if you're developing your app in the windows environment, the cronR package is not available (as there is no cron job in windows :-). For that you can test in a docker environment.